# Node.JS: execFile ENOENT

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I've tried to execute `*.exe` file, but got:

`exec error:  { Error: spawn ${__dirname}/install.exe ENOENT`

Code:

```
var execFile = require('child_process').execFile
execFile('${__dirname}/install.exe', function(error, stderr) {
   console.log('stderr: ', __dirname);
   if (error !== null) {
       console.log('exec error: ', error);
   }
  });
```

Also tried: `'${__dirname}\install.exe'`, `'./install.exe'`, `'D:\install.exe'`

Comment: Do you mean to use template literals? You have to use backticks: `\`${__dirname}/install.exe\``. `'${__dirname}/install.exe'` creates a string that *literally* contains the character sequence `${__dirname}`.

Comment: @FelixKling, same again..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@FelixKling has the right advice; variables don't work unless you create your string with back-ticks. Additionally, it's a good idea to use the `path` module to resolve file paths:

```
var path = require('path');
var execFile = require('child_process').execFile;

var exePath = path.resolve(__dirname, './install.exe');
execFile(exePath, function(error, stderr) {
   console.log('stderr: ', __dirname);
   if (error !== null) {
       console.log('exec error: ', error);
   }
});
```

**Edit**:

This is for your original question, about `ENOENT`; for your second about `UNKNOWN` errors, the cause can vary. It sounds like it might be a permissions issue since the executable needs to elevate to administrator permissions.

Comment: Besides, when i'm using `path.resolve(__dirname, './install.exe')` - i'm getting erorr: `error: spawn UNKNOWN`

Comment: Your path to the executable is incorrect, then. You should add to your question what your directory structure looks like, or there's no way we can guess what the file path should be. `__dirname` is the path to your source file's directory, in case you didn't know that.

Comment: Double-checked everything

Comment: When i'm providing INVALID path (of unexisted file) i'm getting `error: ENOENT` instead of `error: spawn UNKNOWN` in case of valid file path.

Comment: Are you sure it's an executable? Can you run it manually? It may be blocked by Windows, or incompatible with your OS... really `UNKNOWN` is a catch-all for anything Node isn't aware of.

Comment: Apparently it is 'Run as administrator' problem. Bad error description... Please edit your answer so i could accept it

Comment: And 1 more thing, if there is the way to run any extensions of the file? (just tried *.avi and got UNKNOWN error). It is important not only  run but to control with callbacks like in case of child processes

Comment: `spawn` is specifically for executables; you could try to spawn `start` with the AVI file path as an argument.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Just googled 'child proccesses callbacks' and got nothing. But when i tried proc.on('close', ..) - it is working. So why there is no information about it? it is standard callback? where can i get list of those callbacks? Thank you very much!

Comment: Events for process objects are defined here: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_close